# ASP.NET c# Gridview OnRowUpdating not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm working in Visual Studio 2015.
When the Gridview loads, I can click on "Edit".
When I click Cancel I'm just getting back to the Gridview. 
So that good, but if I click "Update" he is doing the same thing as what is happening at "Cancel". No errors.

Here is the method for the OnRowUpdating :

```
protected void UpdateHandleiding(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {         
            SqlConnection Sqlconnection1 = new SqlConnection();
            Sqlconnection1.ConnectionString = (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            //string ID = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblID")).Text;
            //string Naam = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtNaam")).Text;
            //string URL = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtURL")).Text;

            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
            string Naam = (row.Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
            string URL = (row.Cells[2].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Handleidingen SET Naam=@Naam, URL=@URL WHERE ID=@ID"))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naam", Naam);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@URL", URL);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }

            }

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Here is my OnRowEditing & OnRowCancelingEdit which do work :

```
    protected void EditHandleiding(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        ShowHandleidingen();
    }
    protected void CancelEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        ShowHandleidingen();
    }
```

Here is my Gridview :

```
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="grid-center" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        DataKeyNames="ID" EnableModelValidation="True" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"
                        OnRowEditing="EditHandleiding" OnRowUpdating="UpdateHandleiding" OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEdit">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Naam" HeaderText="Naam"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="URL" HeaderText="URL"/>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is simple situation caused by the post back events in asp.net, in the Update Method the page is reloaded from the begining, even if you give new values to the data that you want too submit in the database, asp.net will take the one in the page_load method, when you fill the database in the first place at the page_load method add this condition :

```
   private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       // Fill up the gridView with the data that you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
```

{

}

replace `object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e`

to

```
object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e
```

Comment: 'GridViewRowEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'RowIndex' and no extension method 'RowIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'GridViewRowEventArgs' could be found

Answer (score 0):

Simply change gridview in aspx page

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
```

and then put

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
```

{}